# Toggling an element that appears twice on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with an html component that appears twice on a page.

The issue I am having is that when I click one component to toggle it's content (like an accordion) both components toggle simultaneously.

How can I rewrite the JS to toggle each component when I click them separately, without giving the components different classes and rewriting the js twice?

This is what I have so far;

```
var bindEventsToUI = function () {        
        $(".details").click(function(e){
            $(".content").slideToggle("slow", function() {
                $(e.target).hide().siblings().show();
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: Is each `.content` a child of each `.details`, by any chance?

Comment: The answer will depend on your HTML structure (specifically where each `.content` is relative to the `.details` component you want to control it.)

Comment: @matmo Without additional details, I assumed this to be the case with my answer below, which demonstrates using `$(this).children()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(".details").click(function(e) {
  $(this).children(".content").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='details'>Testing 123
  <div class='content'>> Content 123</div>
</div>
<div class='details'>Testing 456
  <div class='content'>> Content 456</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd use `$(e).find(".content")` instead in case `.content` isn't an immediate child of `.details`, but this is the general solution I'd go with also (assuming `.content`s are children of `.details`, of course.

Comment: Thanks, and agreed!  It was a simple illustration given there was no information related to the html structure, but `.find()` is the right choice if `.content` is deeper than one level below `.details`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a different identifier for each element. I would recommend an `id`:

```
var bindEventsToUI = function () {//element) {        
    $("#id1 .details").click(function(e){
        $("#id1 .content").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(e.target).hide().siblings().show();
        });
    });
    $("#id2 .details").click(function(e){
        $("#id2 .content").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(e.target).hide().siblings().show();
        });
    });
    //..and so on
};
```

Or, you could use the `closest` function:

```
var bindEventsToUI = function () {//element) {        
    $(".details").click(function(e){
        $(this).closest(".content").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(e.target).hide().siblings().show();
        });
    });
};
```